# After Implementing Flask Application Factory, terminal command "Flask run" not working

Tags: python, flask, design-patterns, environment-variables

I have the following problem,

I'm learning Flask and I'm at a point where I'm installing a Flask application factory, after installing the factory everything works when I call the app.py directly from the console, but I can't do any more commands through Flask.

For example:

> flask db migrate -m "add language to posts"

or

> flask run

or any other flask comment gives my this:

> Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'app'.
> Use 'FLASK_APP=app:name' to specify one

i have already set all enviroment variables manually, but the error does not go away,
how can I fix this without removing the application factory again?

**my normal procedure to start the app**

```
> source My_Flask_App/venv/bin/activate
> flask run
```

the variables that are needed actually come from the .flaskenv, since the rebuild this doesn't seem to work, manually setting the enviroment variable by export FLASK_APP=app.py doesn't bring any change either

My folder structure :

```
My_Flask_App/
    |
    |___app/
    |    |
    |    |__auth
    |    |    |
    |    |    __init__.py
    |    |    routes.py
    |    |    
    |    |__errors
    |    |    |
    |    |    __init__.py
    |    |    routes.py
    |    |    
    |    |__main
    |    |    |
    |    |    __init__.py
    |    |    routes.py
    |    |    
    |    |__static
    |    |    ...
    |    |    
    |    |__templates
    |    |    |
    |    |    |__auth
    |    |    |    *html files
    |    |    |
    |    |    |__email
    |    |    |    *html files
    |    |    |
    |    |    |__errors
    |    |    |    *html files
    |    |    |
    |    |    |__user
    |    |    |    *html files
    |    |    |
    |    |    _post.html
    |    |    base.html
    |    |    index.html
    |    |    messages.html
    |    |    navbar.html
    |    |         
    |    |__translations
    |    |
    |    __init__.py
    |    models.py
    |
    |___migrations
    |
    .flaskenv
    app.db
    app.py
    config.py
```

**My_Flask_App/app/__init__.py**

> ```
> import logging
> import os
> from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler, SMTPHandler
>
> from flask import Flask, current_app, request
> from flask_babel import Babel
> from flask_babel import lazy_gettext as _l
> from flask_login import LoginManager
> from flask_mail import Mail
> from flask_migrate import Migrate
> from flask_moment import Moment
> from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
>
> db = SQLAlchemy()
> migrate = Migrate()
> login = LoginManager()
> login.login_view = "auth.login"  
> login.login_message = _l("Please log in to access this page.") 
> mail = Mail()
> moment = Moment()
> babel = Babel()
>
>
> def init_app():
>     """Initialize the core application."""
>     app: Flask = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
>     app.config.from_object("config.Config")
>
>     db.init_app(app)
>     migrate.init_app(app, db)
>     login.init_app(app)
>     mail.init_app(app)
>     moment.init_app(app)
>     babel.init_app(app)
>
>     with app.app_context():
>         from app.admin import admin_blueprint
>         from app.auth import auth_blueprint
>         from app.errors import error_blueprint
>         from app.main import main_blueprint
>
>         app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix="/admin")
>         app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix="/auth")
>         app.register_blueprint(error_blueprint)
>         app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
>
>         return app
>
>
> @babel.localeselector
> def get_locale():
>     return request.accept_languages.best_match(current_app.config["LANGUAGES"])
> ```

**My_Flask_App/app.py**

> ```
> from app import db, init_app
> from app.models import Post, User
> from config import Config
> from private_config import PrivateConfig
>
> app = init_app()
>
>
> @app.shell_context_processor
> def make_shell_context():
>     return {"db": db, "User": User, "Post": Post}
>
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     app.run()
> ```

**My_Flask_App/config.py**

> ```
> import os
>
> from dotenv import load_dotenv
>
> basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
> load_dotenv(os.path.join(basedir, ".flaskenv"))
>
>
> class Config(object):
>     SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
>     SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
>     SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(basedir, "app.db")
>     POSTS_PER_PAGE = 20
>     MAIL_SERVER = "smtp.gmail.com"
>     MAIL_PORT = 587
>     MAIL_USE_TLS = True
>     SENDER_EMAIL = os.environ.get("SENDER_EMAIL")
>     MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get("MAIL_USERNAME")
>     MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("MAIL_PASSWORD")
>     LANGUAGES = ["en", "de"]
> ```

**My_Flask_App/app/.flaskenv**

> ```
> FLASK_APP=app.py
> FLASK_ENV=development
> ```

Why does the Flask command no longer work since the change? and how can I get it to work again?

Answer (score 0):

Okay after very many attempts of debugging, I have found the solution....

1. terminal: I closed the terminal and this time also killed all the still hanging processes of the terminal, and they there, it works fine.
2. the filename "app.py" caused additional errors, I guess that there were internal problems to distinguish the filename app from the global variable app.

If you were to recreate the problem to give me an answer, thank you very much anyway, but you can stop looking :)